# Any lightweight *nix environment for programming

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

Is there any lightweight *nix OS dedicated for programming purposes?

Actually, I have a full installation of Mandriva in my computer; but sometimes in Windows I must use Virtualbox to run some *nix OS.

Because I only need the OS for only programming in this case, so I just want to ask you about it. Of course, I searched about this on the net; but I also want to have your opinions...

Basically I need C/C++, Java, Python environment.

Comment: I wish someone would create a "bash" shell in a browser... Even if it required flash... It'd be awesome to be able to have command line access to a unix shell account via a browser...

Comment: @dicroce: Just get a shell account somewhere and run http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/ or http://anyterm.org/ or something like that.

Comment: @dicroce The idea of using a web browser for any computer activity you are supposed to do is a bit silly. Just `ssh` to your Unix box and start programming.

Comment: @israkir, I released a custom, minimalist version of Ubuntu focused on Haskell programming. http://www.yellosoft.us/gak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, a machine that you do development on shouldn't be lightweight.  It should be heavy. full of compilers, interpreters, profilers, debuggers, IDEs, editors, benchmarks, checked-out code from repos, development versions of system libraries, test suites, generated large test files, backup tools, virtual machines, chroots, music to set-up comfort environment, mail, office suite to do the paperwork.

I mean, install [Putty](http://www.putty.org) and connect to your machine (a), or do all development on virtual machine (b), that is kept on external hard drive (that's what I did, when I needed this), so you can use it everywhere where VirtualBox can run.

As for linuxes, I personally *would like* to use Gentoo Linux, as it can be *customized* to be lightweight.  But unless you're really experienced with all linux administration stuff, customization may take a lot of time.  So as a (c) variant, I'd advise to use *any* distribution (like your Mandriva), because normally base system takes about 10% of "weight" that you need for development on top of that.

And, by the way, boot speed is irrelevant on VirtualBox, since you can save virtual machine state entirely on hard drive and restore it within seconds.

Comment: As for starters Ubuntu can be good. I am used to Fedora though.

Answer (score 9):

The only Linux distro you should use is [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/). Please read [why it is so great](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux) for developers :)

I'm an Arch Linux user, so my opinion may be biased.

Comment: I'm also an Arch fan - build your system with what you want/need and nothing more!

Answer (score 2):

I have a Debian install with X, windowmaker, firefox, vim, gcc, make and dependencies.  Also, source control tools.  Not much more, other than stuff that's useful in shell scripts.  About 1.4G used on disk.  Boots quickly.  Very little BS involved.

I used to use OpenBSD on my old laptop.  Similar to the above, but even more minimalist.  You upgrade the OS with tar and patch.  :-)  Very nice, very small.  Only reason I switched away from it is because I got a new machine which needed ndiswrapper for wifi...

PS: seems like this should be a community wiki...

Comment: Don't get me wrong; Debian is easily my favourite distro.  BUT...1.4G is HUGE for a basic coding environment.  I used to run X on yggdrassil or slackware in about 12MB of memory (4MB of swap over what I actually had in physical RAM), and I think about 30MB of disk space.  From the Walnut Creek CDROM advert: "Linux uses as little as 2 MB of hard disk space or as much as 680 MB." -- http://www.vectorbd.com/bfd/bbsinfo/walnut.inf

Comment: I generally agree.  For the latest OpenBSD release, I got the base system on the ftp with "mget bsd* *.tgz" and the result was 232 MB.  But Debian can be at least less bloated than something that ships with GNOME or KDE by default.

Comment: Sure, it's pretty big - but then again, 1.4G is likely to be smaller than your swapfile on Windows, so it's also pretty small when you look at in the context of current disk sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/).  I keep a full programming environment on a 4GB thumb drive with me at all times... just in case.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about Cygwin, which gives you a Unix-like environment right within your Windows box.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like [Puppy](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=puppy) or [DSL](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=damnsmall)?

They aren't dedicated to programming, but they *are* small and lightweight.

Comment: Well, I didn't like Puppy, but will give a try DSL:)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like [GRML](http://grml.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to do in terms of development.

Questions I would ask myself before development.

a) Who is the audience of the applications?

b) Is it a web based application or a desktop application?

c) How heavy is the number crunching part?

The first questions sometimes dictate the programming language you will be using.  If it is for system administrator, I believe you will be writing a console application with command line interface, that the choice would be using programming language like shell scripts languages, C, C++, and a few other script languages like Python and Ruby.

For second question, If you are doing a web based application or mobile application, you would need to get the SDK with the libraries, and it would pretty much dictate the environment you will be working on.

For the number crunching part, you would need to look into libraries like CUDA or Fortran libraries that are designed for these type of applications.

Personally I use the Gentoo and Puppy Linux distro.  If you need do C, Java and python, you could just download the stage3 tar ball of Gentoo linux, download the SDK from Oracle, and you are set to go.

Sometimes people want to do the developement in Windows environment, and don't want to miss the Unix tools, using cygwin and mingw in Windows environment would be viable options.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trisquel mini is the best which is also ubuntu based. I am using it.I installed eclipse ide in it with 1 gb ram. It uses only 200 mb for running os for more information visit my  https://hassan004.blogspot.com/2022/01/weight-linux-distro-trisquel-mini.html